# Footable and Validation error message in Mobile view MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, validation, footable

In my MVC 5 Web App I use footable. In a table I have fields radio buttons for example that are built the form.

here is the code:

```
  <thead>

            <tr>
                <th></th>
                @foreach (var labelfreqdep in ViewBag.rbFreqDep)
                { 

                    <th style="text-align:center;" data-breakpoints="xs sm">

                        <label for="FrequencyID">@labelfreqdep.FrequencyDescription</label>

                    </th>

                }

                <th data-breakpoints="xs sm"></th>
            </tr>
     </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td>First Chooses</td>
                @foreach (var freqdep in ViewBag.rbFreqDep)
                {
                    <td class="rd">

                        <input type="radio" name="A3_1" id="A3_1" value="@freqdep.FrequencyDescription" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please select">
                    </td>

                }
                <td class="rd">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.A3_1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</td>

            </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
```

I also use validation for empty fields with data-val="true". The problem is that doesn't display the "Please select" message in mobile view. It works ok for desktop view. When I have expanded the tr with the plus icon the message appears. Can we just expand the rows on submit so the message to be displayed?

Any idea?

**Edited**

I used

```
   $("#survey_form").submit(function (event) {
        $('.surveytable').footable({
            "expandAll": true
        });
      });`
```

It expands the rows on submit but it doesn't show the validation errors

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has the same issue, I solved it by giving an id to the button and then handle it through jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function($){
    $('.surveytable').footable()


    $("#survey_btn").click(function (event) {
        $('.surveytable').footable({
            "expandAll": true

        });

    });

 });
</script>
```